# Cortar json en flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicación en flutter, y me gustaria saber si alguien sabe como hacer para recortar el json, lo que pasa es que sólo necesito lo que está a adentro del recordset

Investigando por internet no he encontrado mucho, pero sería de gran ayuda si me explican como se podría hacer.

Lo siguiente es lo que recibo cuando hago una petición http, entonces yo lo que necesito en flutter es recibir los restaurantes y poner cada uno en diferentes objetos para mostrarlos en pantalla.

```
"recordset": [
    {
      "idNegocios": 1,
      "calle": "Zapopan",
      "numInterior": "2205",
      "numExterior": null,
      "colonia": "Buena Vista",
      "tipoServicio": "Restaurante",
      "tipoComida": "Pizzeria",
      "ciudades_idCiudades": 1,
      "telefono_telefono": "8781246237",
      "nombre": "Manhattan"
    },
    {
      "idNegocios": 2,
      "calle": "San antonio",
      "numInterior": "205",
      "numExterior": null,
      "colonia": "Cumbres",
      "tipoServicio": "Cafeteria",
      "tipoComida": "Cafe",
      "ciudades_idCiudades": 1,
      "telefono_telefono": "8781234567",
      "nombre": "Starbucks"
    }
]
```

Que quede algo así:

```dart
    {
      "idNegocios": 1,
      "calle": "Zapopan",
      "numInterior": "2205",
      "numExterior": null,
      "colonia": "Buena Vista",
      "tipoServicio": "Restaurante",
      "tipoComida": "Pizzeria",
      "ciudades_idCiudades": 1,
      "telefono_telefono": "8781246237",
      "nombre": "Manhattan"
    },
    {
      "idNegocios": 2,
      "calle": "San antonio",
      "numInterior": "205",
      "numExterior": null,
      "colonia": "Cumbres",
      "tipoServicio": "Cafeteria",
      "tipoComida": "Cafe",
      "ciudades_idCiudades": 1,
      "telefono_telefono": "8781234567",
      "nombre": "Starbucks"
    }
```

tengo lo siguiente y no me funciona, ya que necesito conseguir los objetos y el json solo lo reconoce con json['Recordset'][0][midato]

```
factory Restaurante.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Restaurante(
      idNegocio     : json['Recordset'][0]['idNegocio'],
      calle         : json['Recordset'][0]['calle'],
      numInterior   : json['Recordset'][0]['numInterior'],
      numExterior   : json['Recordset'][0]['numExterior'],
      colonia       : json['Recordset'][0]['colonia'],
      tipoServicio  : json['Recordset'][0]['tipoServicio'],
      tipoComida    : json['Recordset'][0]['tipoComida'],
      idCiudad      : json['Recordset'][0]['Ciudades_idCiudades'].cast<int>(),
      telefono      : json['Recordset'][0]['telefono_telefono'],
      nombre        : json['Recordset'][0]['nombre']
    );
  }
```

Comment: Me parece que lo que quieres no es cortar, si no obtener los datos de `recordset`

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo, lo que quieres es utilizar los datos dentro del arreglo, una forma de hacerlo seria crear una clase separada.

```
class Registros {
    List<Recordset> recordset;

    Registros({
        this.recordset,
    });

    factory Registros.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Registros(
        recordset: List<Recordset>.from(json["recordset"].map((x) => Recordset.fromJson(x))),
    );

}

class Recordset {
    int idNegocios;
    String calle;
    String numInterior;
    dynamic numExterior;
    String colonia;
    String tipoServicio;
    String tipoComida;
    int ciudadesIdCiudades;
    String telefonoTelefono;
    String nombre;

    Recordset({
        this.idNegocios,
        this.calle,
        this.numInterior,
        this.numExterior,
        this.colonia,
        this.tipoServicio,
        this.tipoComida,
        this.ciudadesIdCiudades,
        this.telefonoTelefono,
        this.nombre,
    });

    factory Recordset.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Recordset(
        idNegocios: json["idNegocios"],
        calle: json["calle"],
        numInterior: json["numInterior"],
        numExterior: json["numExterior"],
        colonia: json["colonia"],
        tipoServicio: json["tipoServicio"],
        tipoComida: json["tipoComida"],
        ciudadesIdCiudades: json["ciudades_idCiudades"],
        telefonoTelefono: json["telefono_telefono"],
        nombre: json["nombre"],
    );
}
```

Cuando recibes los datos en formato **json** lo pasamos por el metodo `fromJson`, lo cual te dará un objeto de tipo `Registros`

```
final _registros = Registros.fromJson(json);
```

Para recorrer cada uno de los datos podrías hacerlo con un `for` a lo que seria `_registros.recordset`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que necesito obtener el conjunto de los datos, y como me llega el json con esa estructura, pues no me deja tomar cada uno de los datos, ya que tengo que estar llamando de uno por uno [recordset][0][miDato], el segundo [recordset][1][miDato] y así sucesivamente

Comment: @Fernando ok entiedo que obtendrás dato por dato, la forma en lo que te lo proporciono los almacena todos en un array de tipo `Recordset ` podrías editar tu pregunta y proporcionar el error que te genera